# numpy: How can I select specific indexes in an np array for k-fold cross validation?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning, cross-validation

I have a training data set in matrix form of dimensions 5000 x 3027 (CIFAR-10 data set). Using array_split in numpy, I partitioned it into 5 different parts, and I want to select just one of the parts as the cross validation fold. However my problem comes when I use something like
XTrain[[Indexes]] where indexes is an array like [0,1,2,3], because doing this gives me a 3D tensor of dimensions 4 x 1000 x 3027, and not a matrix. How do I collapse the "4 x 1000" into 4000 rows, to get a matrix of 4000 x 3027?

```
for fold in range(len(X_train_folds)):
    indexes = np.delete(np.arange(len(X_train_folds)), fold) 
    XTrain = X_train_folds[indexes]
    X_cv = X_train_folds[fold]
    yTrain = y_train_folds[indexes]
    y_cv = y_train_folds[fold]

    classifier.train(XTrain, yTrain)
    dists = classifier.compute_distances_no_loops(X_cv)
    y_test_pred = classifier.predict_labels(dists, k)

    num_correct = np.sum(y_test_pred == y_test)
    accuracy = float(num_correct/num_test)
    k_to_accuracy[k] = accuracy
```

Comment: Can you share the code you're having trouble with?

Comment: Added the code, the shape of XTrain = X_train_folds[indexes] is 4 x 1000 x 3027, but I'm hoping to get it to become 4000 x 3027

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) package. It already comes with plenty of common machine learning tools, such as [K-fold cross-validation generator](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html):

```
>>> from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
>>> X = # your data [samples x features]
>>> y = # gt labels
>>> kf = KFold(X.shape[0], n_folds=5)
```

And then, iterate through `kf`:

```
>>> for train_index, test_index in kf:
        X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
        # do something
```

The above loop will be executed `n_folds` times, each time with different training and testing indexes.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you can try this instead (new to numpy so if I am doing something inefficient/wrong, would be happy to be corrected)

```
X_train_folds = np.array_split(X_train, num_folds)
y_train_folds = np.array_split(y_train, num_folds)
k_to_accuracies = {}

for k in k_choices:
    k_to_accuracies[k] = []
    for i in range(num_folds):
        training_data, test_data = np.concatenate(X_train_folds[:i] + X_train_folds[i+1:]), X_train_folds[i]
        training_labels, test_labels = np.concatenate(y_train_folds[:i] + y_train_folds[i+1:]), y_train_folds[i]
        classifier.train(training_data, training_labels)
        predicted_labels = classifier.predict(test_data, k)
        k_to_accuracies[k].append(np.sum(predicted_labels == test_labels)/len(test_labels))
```